# getSelectionTitlePrice() only show special price for bundle product

Tags: magento-1.9, bundled-product, tierprice

I have a **bundle product**, and the function to show the price for product options is : `$this->getSelectionTitlePrice()`, which only show me the special price.

What I need to do if I also what to display the **original price**?

Answer (score 0):

```
Mage::getModel('bundle/product_price')->getTotalPrices($_product,'max',1); //price including tax

Mage::getModel('bundle/product_price')->getTotalPrices($_product,'max',0); //price excluding tax
```

Comment: This only give me the final price. I also want to show the original price of a bundle product.